# How to set a empty value in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, null, handler

i have this code and i have a little problem, when i edit, i have the `rowid` value in `codSelected` to send to my handler, its stored by `onSelectRow` event. If I edit a row, works well, but if edit one and inmediately i want to add a new one, i need this value (`_codSelected`) null, but it has the same value of the last edited row. I know that i can use `addfunc` in the pager, but if i use this, i cant use the popup window that jqGrid use by default.

Thanks.

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: '/modulos/mantenimiento/Proveedores.ashx', 
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Codigo' //Some more colnames and colmodels]
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Codigo', index: 'PRg_Codigo', edittype: 'select',
            editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, editoptions:
            { size: 30, dataUrl: '/modulos/mantenimiento/grupoProveedores.ashx?
            oper=selectAllGroups' }, sortable: true }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        _codSelected = rowid;
    },
    ajaxSelectOptions: {
        data: {
            codSelected: function () { 
                return _codSelected;
            }
        }
    }
});

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    alerttext: "Seleccione un Servicio.",
    add: true, addtitle: "Crear nuevo Servicio",
    del: true, deltitle: "Eliminar Servicio",
    edit: true, edittitle: "Modificar Servicio",
    search: false, searchtitle: "Búsqueda",
    refresh: true,
    cloneToTop: true
},
{ width: 360, resize: false, closeAfterEdit: true, recreateForm: true,
    viewPagerButtons: true, afterComplete: muestraResultadoOperacion },
{ width: 360, resize: false, closeAfterAdd: true, recreateForm: true,
    viewPagerButtons: true, afterComplete: muestraResultadoOperacion },
{},
{ closeAfterSearch: true, closeOnEscape: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand full your requirements.

First of all `_codSelected` seems is the same as the value of internal `selrow` option of jqGrid. You can use `$("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow")` to get the `rowid` of the last selected row. If you want to initialize the `_codSelected` variable to the value of the current selected row *only in case of Edit dialog and set it to `null` in case of Add dialog* you can do this inside of [beforeInitData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) callback. The `beforeInitData` callback for Add dialog can set `_codSelected` to `null` and the same callback for Edit dialog can use `_codSelected = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");`. It should solve your problem.

**UPDATED**: To clear my suggestion I decide to post the following code:

```js
var _codSelected = null;

// ...
// here should be the definition of jqGrid where you removed
// the current code of onSelectRow which changes _codSelected
// ...

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    alerttext: "Seleccione un Servicio.",
    add: true, addtitle: "Crear nuevo Servicio",
    del: true, deltitle: "Eliminar Servicio",
    edit: true, edittitle: "Modificar Servicio",
    search: false, searchtitle: "Búsqueda",
    refresh: true,
    cloneToTop: true
},
{ width: 360, resize: false, closeAfterEdit: true, recreateForm: true,
    beforeInitData: function () {
        // set _codSelected in case of Edit operation
        _codSelected = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
    },
    viewPagerButtons: true, afterComplete: muestraResultadoOperacion },
{ width: 360, resize: false, closeAfterAdd: true, recreateForm: true,
    beforeInitData: function () {
        // clear _codSelected in case of Add operation
        _codSelected = null;
    },
    viewPagerButtons: true, afterComplete: muestraResultadoOperacion },
{},
{ closeAfterSearch: true, closeOnEscape: true });
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, but how can i do the case of the action (edit or add) inside beforeinitdata function? Which variable have to compare? Thanks.

Comment: @bombai: Sorry, but the code which you posted has no `formatter: "actions"`. What you mean exactly? There are many ways to implement form editing and inline editing. You can specify `beforeInitData` callback in any implementation which use form editing, but you should describe exactly the problem which you have.

Comment: Hi Oleg, i use form editing, and i dont know very well how can use formatter options, i am reading about it. Here you can see a screenshot of my grid, http://i.imgbox.com/adg0GLTy.jpg
 and the problem is if i edit before add, when i add i need to set null _codSelected because this variable is setted before in onSelectRow(editing), and i want to send this variable empty not with the last edit value when i press the add button. Can you understand me? Many thanks.

Comment: @bombai: You used just the word "action" in the previous comment. So I misunderstood what you want. The previous on your current question I posted already. Probably it's better if I add the fragment of the code. I'll write it now. It will be exactly the same as I wrote you before, but in the code.

Comment: many thanks. My mistake was that i dont know where i have to include beforeinitdata function, that's in every action, i put in the same position of, for example, onselectRow before!

Comment: @bombai: Not a problem. You are welcome! It's important only that the problem is solved at the end. Best wishes!

Comment: To dont add a new question for one little thing, if the formatter is date, can i include a calendar in the text field of start and end data?

Comment: @bombai: Yes, you can. If you call `$(elem).datepicker({...})` inside of `dataInit` you can use any options of `datepicker`. For example: `maxDate: new Date(2013, 11, 31)` or `maxDate: '+1y'`. You can use `minDate: new Date(2006, 0, 1)` or something like `yearRange: 'c-2:c+1'`. You should just decide which option(s) is(are) the best in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I have a little problem! If i have three columns in the colmodel, and one is hidden and hasnt a value, when i press add button i want to assign on it a value, is it possible with setGridparam? If I have "ID, name and surname" columns, this ID is global and is a hidden column, but if i create a 3 new rows, ID will have the same value always and i have this value on the page before to press any button on the grid in a variable, and i need to set this value on this column value.. Thanks again!

Comment: @bombai: It's very important to implement Add row on the server side correctly. I mean that the server should generate `Id` for the new row (typically it's id from the corresponding table in the database). You need *additionally* implement `afterSubmit` (in case of form editing if you use `reloadAfterSubmit: false`) or `aftersavefunc` (in case of inline editing) which decode the id returned from the server. If you have no hidden (or non-hidden) ID column the `afterSubmit` should returns decoded id as the 3d element of the array. If you have id column it should made some changes additionally.